# Create a CData-typed buffer in Python with CFFI

Tags: python, c, buffer, python-cffi

I am trying to create a buffer with a special type in Python, to send it to a C function wrapped with CFFI.

In C, I have something like:

```
typedef unsigned char UINT8;
typedef UINT8* PUINT8;
```

Then, in Python, the above lines are in the `ffi.cdef()` and my buffer instantiation code looks like:

```
nb_buffer = 8
buffer_size = 42

buffers = ffi.new( "PUINT8[]", nb_buffer )

for i in range( nb_buffer ):
    tmp_buffer = ffi.buffer( ffi.new( "UINT8[]", 1 ), buffer_size )
    buffers[ i ] = ffi.cast( "PUINT8", ffi.from_buffer( tmp_buffer ) )

c.function( buffers )
```

The C function receives a UINT8**.

And... that ends with a segmentation fault a little bit further, in the C function.

So I `print buffers[ i ]` after using `ffi.cast`:

```
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbaca0>
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbacd8>
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbaca0>
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbacd8>
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbaca0>
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbacd8>
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbaca0>
<cdata 'unsigned char *' 0x2cbacd8>
```

What am I missing? Is the buffer being garbage collected as soon as it overwrites `tmp_buffer`?

Comment: Not looking in details, but ``ffi.buffer( ffi.new( "UINT8[]", 1 ), ... )`` is basically wrong.  It means "allocate an array (of one UINT8); then take a buffer to it; then forget immediately the new array, so that it is immediately freed".

Comment: Also, you allocate arrays of one UINT8 and then consider them as 42-bytes buffers.  The last 41 bytes are not allocated anyway.

Comment: I thought the importance of the first parameter of `ffi.buffer()` was the type of the CData, not its length (as it is the second parameter) and that it would somehow create a given-CData-typed buffer of the given size. But I now understand that that second parameter is for slicing a memory size that would be bigger than needed. Thanks Armin! I will try your answer asap.

Comment: `ffi.buffer()` is not allocating any memory, it is merely returning a view over existing memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
buffers = ffi.new( "PUINT8[]", nb_buffer )
keepalive = []

for i in range( nb_buffer ):
    p = ffi.new("UINT8[]", buffer_size)
    keepalive.append(p)
    buffers[i] = p

c.function( buffers )

# keepalive stays alive at least until here
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
keepalive = [ ffi.new( "UINT8[]", buffer_size ) for i in range( nb_buffer ) ]
buffers = ffi.new( "PUINT8[]", keepalive )

c.functions( buffers )

# keepalive stays alive at least until here
```